# Typescript directive html template in gulp

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp

I am looking at switching from Grunt to Gulp and I have everything I need working except for one thing.

When I was using Grunt, I used grunt-ts and it had a very nice feature for dealing with html templates for angular directives. https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ts#html

It takes my directive template html file and creates a .ts file for it. This fits very nicely into our build process since all .ts-files are compiled and concat:ed to one file.
Now, when I use gulp-typescript(https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) I no longer have this feature. 
Is there a way to recreate the functionality from grunt-ts to the Gulp workflow?

Basically, what I need to do is:

Watch all *.tpl.html files in a specified directory. [No problem]

When file is changed, minify the html contents (using gulp-minify-html) in the file and add the minified html content to a new file(in the same directory) with this file content:

```
module [directivename].tpl{ 
    export var html ='MINIFIEDHTML';
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this? Or is there a better way to do this?
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe gulp-angular-templatecache is what you need.

```
var templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('templates/**/*.html')
    .pipe(templateCache())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});
```

You can see how John papa does that from [here](http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-and-gulp/)

Comment: Thanks, looks very promising! I will try it out.